# MySQL UPDATE syntax with multiple tables using WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

### Case:

How to update `table1` with data from `table2` where `id` is equal?

### Problem:

When I run the following update statement, it updates all the records in `table1` (even where the `id` field in `table1` does not exist in `table2`).

How can I use the the multiple update table syntax, to update ONLY the records in `table1` ONLY where the `id` is present in `table2` and equal?

```
UPDATE table1,table2
SET table1.value=table2.value 
WHERE table2.id=table1.id
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

here's the correct syntax of `UPDATE` with join in `MySQL`

```
UPDATE  table1 a
        INNER JOIN table2 b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
SET     a.value = b.value
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ffb6/1)

Comment: I can see it is a bit different thanthan what @peterm wrote... how is this the correct one? Thank You in advance, love to learn this stuff

Comment: the syntax of @peterm is also correct but it works on `SQL Server` not on `MySQL`.

Comment: This is why I love stack...perfect answer and I did not have to formulate a question already answered here and get flamed for it LOL...great stuff, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**
For MySql it'll be

```
UPDATE table1 t1 INNER JOIN 
       table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
   SET t1.value = t2.value
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4032d/1)

**Original answer** was for SQL Server

```
UPDATE table1
   SET table1.value = table2.value 
  FROM table1 INNER JOIN 
       table2 ON table2.id=table1.id
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79541/1)

Comment: What about using a sub-select? Which is better?

Comment: @BenJones IMHO `JOIN` is the way to go. Sorry didn't pay attention that it was needed for mysql. My original answer was for SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
UPDATE TABLE1
SET column_name = TABLE2.column_name
FROM TABLE1, TABLE2
WHERE TABLE1.id = TABLE2.id
```

Comment: I don't think that will address the issue I am having of updating all the records in table1?

Comment: If so, you mention all the column names

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.value = (select table2.value 
WHERE table2.id=table1.id)
```