# mysql update with several joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I would like to update with 2 join.... but :

```
 UPDATE glpi.glpi_users 
FROM
    glpi.glpi_groups_users
    INNER JOIN glpi.glpi_groups ON glpi.glpi_groups_users.groups_id = glpi.glpi_groups.id
    INNER JOIN glpi.glpi_users ON glpi.glpi_users.id = glpi.glpi_groups_users.users_id 
    SET glpi.glpi_users.id = 2 
WHERE
    glpi.glpi_groups.`name` LIKE 'technique'
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM
>           glpi.glpi_groups_users
>           INNER JOIN glpi.glpi_groups ON glpi.glpi_groups_us' at line 2
>   Time: 0s

thanks for your help

Comment: no `FROM` is needed, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037883/mysql-update-syntax-with-multiple-tables-using-where-clause    and  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that the syntax you want is:

```
UPDATE glpi.glpi_users u
INNER JOIN glpi.glpi_groups_users gu ON gu.users_id = u.id
INNER JOIN glpi.glpi_groups g ON g.id = gu.groups_id
SET u.id = 2 
WHERE g.name = 'technique'
```

That is: MySQL update/join syntax doesn't have a `FROM` clause - it looks like `UPDATE ... JOIN ... SET ... WHERE ...`.

Notes:

- since no wildcards do appear in the right side operand, `name LIKE 'technique'` is equivalent to `name = 'technique'`
- table aliases make the query easier to write and read