# Unknown column in 'field list' errno 1054 caused by Trigger

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

I have 2 parent tables (Food, Orders) with one mutual child table (OrderItems)

When using a simple insert query:
INSERT INTO OrderItems (order_id, food_id, quantity) VALUES (111, 18, 2)

**I get the known error: Unknown column in 'field list'**

I've pinpointed the reason to a **trigger** that calculates a queue_time according to food_id * quantity for multiple rows:

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE Orders
    SET queue_time = (
        SELECT SUM(Food.food_time * OrderItems.quantity)
        FROM Food
        WHERE Food.food_id = NEW.food_id
    )
    WHERE Orders.order_id = NEW.order_id;
END
```

The problem lies somewhere at "OrderItems.quantity", since the error does not occur when I replace it by for example 10.

---

I've also tried using this Trigger:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE total_queue_time INT;
    
    SELECT SUM(Food.food_time * NEW.quantity)
    INTO total_queue_time
    FROM Food
    WHERE Food.food_id = NEW.food_id;

    UPDATE Orders
    SET queue_time = total_queue_time
    WHERE Orders.order_id = NEW.order_id;
END;
```

But then the calculation only works for 1 row.

Comment: The query does not contain any `JOIN` for `OrderItems` - where should that come from? Should that be `NEW.quantity` instead?

Comment: see: [MySQL UPDATE syntax with multiple tables using WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15037946/724039)